# what's the simple way to create a DateTime instance based on string?

Tags: parsing, datetime, c#-4.0

For example, how to create an instance of Datetime from string '03/10/2010 12:00:00 AM'?
Any way simple as new DateTime("03/10/2010 12:00:00 AM")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) methods.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("03/10/2010 12:00:00 AM");
```

There are [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wteydsd6.aspx) methods that avoid the possible exception if the passed in string is cannot be parsed.

There are also [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s47fcc.aspx) methods that also take a format string ([standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)) that let you customize the parsing to the exact data/time format you want.

I suggest using the following, ensuring that the date will not be ambiguous (is that March 10th or October 3rd?):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/10/2010 12:00:00 AM", 
                                  "G", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way is using `DateTime.ParseExact()` so you can specify the format
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx